# Why won't this key on my laptop work?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

So recently a sibling accidentally took off the <kbd>W</kbd> key from my laptop. I followed YouTube tutorials on taking out the 2 plastic pieces that surround the rubbery circle  below the key and I removed them without damaging them. After that I noticed that it was a little dirty under the key so I cleaned most of the dirt out. I carefully placed both plastics back inside and it made a click sound so I know I did it right. Finally I put the <kbd>W</kbd> key back on top and pressed down hoping it would be fixed. Now the key is stuck downwards. Usually a key is up and you're able to press it down so it registers, but in my case it's as if it's always being pressed down, as in the key isn't popping back up, but the key also isn't registering, so it's not constantly spamming <kbd>W</kbd>. I don't know what to do. I can't use my <kbd>W</kbd> key because it's not popped upwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely a clip has broken or bent out place. The clips are not repairable. You can try gently removing the key and see if you can ensure the clips are properly in place and then try replacing the key. That might work.

Most likely, you need to replace the keyboard. This is a user replaceable part and is normally easy to do.

Note: The power button on my X230 would not come back up (same issue) and I had to get an original OEM keyboard from a verified vendor on eBay. Laptop is working fine. I had to do this because Lenovo no longer stocks the keyboard for the 6 year old machine.

Comment: Turns out it wasn't the clips that was causing it lol. Some of the rubber spring cup got ripped off and that's why the key wasn't popping back up after I pressed it. I'll just have to get it replaced, unless I'm able to take the spring from another key I don't use and use it to replace the one inside the "W" key, but I doubt I could do that. Thank you for your response tho!

Comment: Thanks for the update and I was happy to help you.